# Renaming folder without breaking solution

Tags: solution

How can I rename a folder without breaking the solution?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you start by tagging your question, and indicating what programming language/framework you're writing about? Your request is not "specific".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, you just open the solution with notepad++ and rename the folder there, and then you rename the folder  outside of the solution. Then check if it doesn't break, otherwise you might've mistyped